# Integrate the differential form over a cardioid

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-forms

$\omega=\dfrac{-ydx+(x-1)dy}{(x-1)^2+y^2}$

Calculate $\int_C\omega$ where $C...r=1+\cos\varphi$ (positively oriented)

I'm still pretty lost when it comes to differential forms but as far as I understand, the form I'm given is actually the change in angle but the origin is shifted to $(1, 0)$. Since the cardioid goes around that point, I think the result should be $2\pi$, right?
If it's true, how can I make it formal?

Comment: Do you have a parametric form for the cardioid ?

Comment: Sure $\gamma (t)=((1+\cos t)\cos t, (1+\cos t)\sin t)$

Comment: Ok just substitute these into the expression and integrate with respect to $t$ from $0$ to $2\pi$. Its a certain amount of work but it should be successful.

Comment: I was hoping I could avoid exactly that with some clever observations and maybe some known result.

Comment: I believe you know amper's law in magnetostatic.after carefully examine expression becomes $F.dr$ where$F$ is similar to the magnetic field due to a current carrying long infinite straight line conductor with a difference in constant,and apply amper's,rearranging,done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let $C$ be the positively oriented cardioid given by the polar equation,
>   $$r(\theta)=1+\cos{\theta},~~~-\pi\le\theta\le\pi.$$
>   Define the one-form $\omega$ as,
>   $$\omega:=\dfrac{-y\,\mathrm{d}x+(x-1)\,\mathrm{d}y}{(x-1)^2+y^2}.$$
>   Calculate the value of the line integral $\oint_{C}\omega$.

To solve this integral we will use the "shifted" polar coordinates $(\rho,\phi)$, which can be converted into the Cartesian coordinates $(x,y)$ by using the equations:

$$\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
x-1&=\rho\cos{\phi},\\
y&=\rho\sin{\phi}.
\end{align}
\end{cases}$$

For $r\ge0$ and $\phi\in(-\pi,\pi]$, the above pair of equations can be solved for $\rho$ and $\phi$ in terms of $(x,y)$ using the [atan2 function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2):

$$\begin{cases}
\rho=\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2},\\
\phi=\operatorname{atan2}{(y,x-1)}=2\arctan{\frac{y}{(x-1)+\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}}}.
\end{cases}$$

Computing the partial derivatives of the last equation we find that:

$$\begin{cases}
\partial_x\phi=\frac{-y}{(x-1)^2+y^2},\\
\partial_y\phi=\frac{x-1}{(x-1)^2+y^2},
\end{cases}$$

and, hence, that the total differential of the angle function $\phi(x,y)$ simply $\omega$:

$$\mathrm{d}\phi=\partial_x\phi\,\mathrm{d}x+\partial_y\phi\,\mathrm{d}y=\frac{-y\,\mathrm{d}x}{(x-1)^2+y^2}+\frac{(x-1)\,\mathrm{d}y}{(x-1)^2+y^2}=\omega.$$

Thus, the line integral we seek is simply:

$$\oint_{C}\omega=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}\phi=\pi-(-\pi)=2\pi$$

Comment: @Fantini Thank you, sir or madame.

Comment: You are welcome. It's sir, by the way haha.